# copying a lot of registry keys

Tags: registry, regedit

I have this huge registry tree i want to copy over and over. Does anyone know how I could copy more than one key at a time ? I have windows xp, and I am using regedit but there is probably a better way for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Found out reg copy could do what i wanted, please close the question.  Thanks !

Comment: You should write this as a full answer of how you solved your problem so that future users can learn - you may even get some rep as well.